# DOM, changing HTML

Tags: dom, queryselector

I have a question about adding/removing in HTML.

I have a list, with, say, 3 li. to add one more li I can use either(coach's ) :

```
const myList = document.querySelector("ul");
const myItem = document.createElement("li");
myList.appendChild(myItem);
```

or, what I liked more for it's shorten way(tutorial's):

```
myList.innerHTML += "<li></li>";
```

but, then, when I wish to remove this added li,(coach's - myItem.remove();) and trying to go the same way as tutorial's, something like:

```
myList.querySelector(li:last-child).innerHTML -= "<li></li>";
```

it is not working. apparently it is fundamentally wrong, but nevertheless is there a solution with innerHTML?

appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't substract a substring from a string, with the `-` operator. The `+` has a special meaning here, it is an alias for String.prototype.concat().

Also

```
myList.querySelector('li:last-child')
```

returns the `<li>` element, so you would have to use outerHTML in this case, to target the `<li></li>` html:

```
myList.querySelector('li:last-child').outerHTML
```

If you want to remove the last `<li></li>` you can use the remove method:

```
myList.querySelector('li:last-child').remove()
```

Or assign an empty string to outerHTML:

```
myList.querySelector('li:last-child').outerHTML = ''
```

Or you could use any string method to manipulate the string before reassigning it:

```
let outerHtml = myList.querySelector('li:last-child').outerHTML;
outerHtml = outerHtml.replace('<li></li>', '');
myList.querySelector('li:last-child').outerHTML = outerHtml;
```